# Problemas com o $ no angular!

Tags: angular

Minha aplicação Angular não está reconhecendo esse carácter **$**

Observem a mensagem de erro que está aparecendo no consoles do navegador;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at novo:21
```

O código é referente a esse abaixo, ele se encontra no arquivo index.html do angular;

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var settings = {
          type: 'json',
          filelimit: 1,
          allow: '*.(jpg|jpeg|png)'
      };

      UIkit.uploadSelect($('#upload-select'), settings);
      UIkit.uploadDrop($('#upload-drop'), settings);
    });
    </script>
```

A página inteira.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kwan</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/assets/css/upload.min.css"/>



</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="../src/assets/javascript/upload.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/assets/javascript/upload.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      var settings = {
          type: 'json',
          filelimit: 1,
          allow: '*.(jpg|jpeg|png)'
      };

      UIkit.uploadSelect($('#upload-select'), settings);
      UIkit.uploadDrop($('#upload-drop'), settings);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como faço pra o Angular reconhecer o **$**  ?

Arquivo angular.cli.json

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js"
      ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá o `$` de acordo com o exemplo mostrado mostra que é um plugin do jQuery que você deseja utilizar.

Para fazer uso do `jQuery` você precisa incluir ele em seu HTML.

Para isso basta você incluir o script diretamente no HTML.

> Exemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kwan</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/assets/css/upload.min.css"/>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <!-- incluindo biblioteca do jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/assets/javascript/upload.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/assets/javascript/upload.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      var settings = {
          type: 'json',
          filelimit: 1,
          allow: '*.(jpg|jpeg|png)'
      };

      UIkit.uploadSelect($('#upload-select'), settings);
      UIkit.uploadDrop($('#upload-drop'), settings);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nota:** O Angular é um Famework que já é popular e com isso possui diversas bibliotecas. Talvez tenha alguma solução que não faça uso do jQuery e caso tenha, eu aconselho o uso.

**Importante:** Caso você não esteja utilizando o `angularjs` recomendo que instale o jquery com o npm e o inclua nos scripts do angular.json como mostrado na resposta da @Leticia.

Comment: eu já tinha incluído o Jquery na minha aplicação como pode ver na atualização da minha postagem,  porém mesmo assim está apresentando problemas, não estou usando angularjs, estou usando Angular 5

Comment: @wladyband faça do jeito em que mostrei, o jQuery do scripts vai ser incluído após a execução de seus scripts. Ou seja no momento em que eles forem executar o script não vai estar disponível. Ou então crie um .js e inclua ele nos scripts após o jQuery.

Comment: desculpe pela minha insistência, pegou, funcionou agora, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Esse script que você está adicionando é JQuery?

Você deve criar um novo arquivo dentro da sua pasta js e importá-lo no seu angular.json dentro da chave de scripts:

Ex:

```
"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "src/js/fechamodal.js",
   "src/js/fileinput.js"
]
```

E então nesse arquivo você pode utilizar o jquery:

Exemplo do meu fechamodal.js:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('#modalLoginForm')) {
        $("#modalLoginForm .close").click()
    }
});
```